# Maven EAR project for multiple application servers

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, websphere, ear

I have a EAR project that I want automatize the building process using maven exclusively.

The EAR project has

- Standard jar modules
- Web modules
- EJB modules
- RAR modules

To be able to execute the product in Jboss 4.2.3 and WebSphere 7 the EJB and RAR descriptors must be configured in different way. Also we have one jar library for each app server.

What I want is to be able to build one EAR for each apps server using the same projects, and for that I need

1. Include a JAR module depending of the app server
2. Use the customized descriptor in the EJB/RAR modules depending of
   the app server
3. Package all this customized modules in an EAR

Can this be done using the same set of project in maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  Have a look at [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) in maven.  They allow you to adjust various things (from the link) like:

- `<repositories>`
- `<pluginRepositories>`
- `<dependencies>`
- `<plugins>`
- `<properties>` (not actually available in the main POM, but used behind the scenes)
- `<modules>`
- `<reporting>`
- `<dependencyManagement>`
- `<distributionManagement>`
- a subset of the  element, which consists of:

  - `<defaultGoal>`
  - `<resources>`
  - `<testResources>`
  - `<finalName>`

Answer (score 0):

The best is to create separate modules like ear-websphere, or ear-jboss and make an appropriate pom file which contains the needed configuration for maven-ear-plugin.